# Is short vector length in PCA problematic? Why are my points so far from my vectors?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, ecology, environmental-data

I am using PCA to examine the relationships between environmental factors of a couple of different types (physical properties, concentrations, relative abundance of genes). I have log-transformed the data, which I think solved issues with scaling. However, when I run the analysis, the points (locations) are very far from one another, making interpretation of the vector relationships difficult.
[image: PCA, clearly the locations are different from one another, but it makes the vectors difficult to interpert]

When I zoom in, I can clearly examine the relationships between vectors but lose a couple of my points (the top left Quality Drain sample for instance)
[image: Zoomed in]

Why are my points so far apart? I assume my points/observations are flying apart because they are simply different from one another but I am concerned that my short vector length may be an issue that is stemming from something I don't understand or am making a mistake.

Comment: This seems like a teachable moment—what do you understand the lengths of the vectors in your plot to mean?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy my understanding is the length of the vectors is a representation of the contribution of each variable to the ordination. Which is why I am somewhat confused because I would assume the vector length would be more variable since there is so much dispersion of points.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy perhaps I am defeating the point of vector length my log transforming?